# how to connect remotely to oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I've installed oracle 11g express edition and sql developer. I don't know ho to connect to a database on remote server. Can anyone help please. Note that I didn't installed any other software like oracle client. Please help, I'm new to this environment

Comment: Hello ling, welcome to DBA.SE. I'm not sure how anyone could help you with your request - you haven't told us what you're trying to connect to what, or what errors you're getting when you try connecting. Please edit your question (there's an edit link right under the tags) to add more details (including exact error messages) so that people can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to connect SQL Developer to an Oracle XE database on a remote host.

- Hit the green plus icon to create a new connection.
- Enter a name of your choice for the new connection
- Enter a username. If you have not yet created a user the "system" user will let you log on and create one.
- Enter your password, if logging on as "system" that will be the password you specified during installation of Oracle XE.
- Change the hostname from "localhost" to the ip address or hostname of your Oracle XE server.

Assuming you installed everything with default options and provided you have nothing blocking the network traffic to port 1521 of your oracle server, you should now be able to connect.

I just happened to see a nice screenshot in another question here: [How to open Oracle listener for three database instances?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/how-to-open-oracle-listener-for-three-database-instances)

I recommend the book [Oracle Database XE 11gR2 Jump Start Guide](http://books.google.no/books/about/Oracle_Database_XE_11gR2_Jump_Start_Guid.html?id=MPTrp712o2gC&redir_esc=y) by Asif Momen to get you started. It's available as an e-book on Amazon or can be read on Safari Books Online, I believe they still offer a free trial.